# I've been trying to connect to the tomcat webapp manager on my Ubuntu-Ec2 Instance.i.e, "myinstanceIP:8080" But this happens

Tags: tomcat, amazon-ec2

This site can’t be reached

**.**.***.** refused to connect.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Answer (score 0):

Your application doesn't appear to be running. use netstat as below to check if your ec2 tomcat server is listening on port 8080

```
netstat -tulpn | grep 8080
```